# Plotly Dash: Live candlestick plot error?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I’m trying to plot live bitcoin price but I keep getting a callback error that says

> updated_btc_2h() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

If I’m making an error elsewhere when trying to plot the candles live, please feel free to let me know!

Code is [here](https://community.plotly.com/t/please-help-with-plot-callback-function-error/46168).

Answer (score 1):

Here is your problem:

```py
@app.callback(
    Output('btc_chart', 'figure'),
    [Input('btc_update', 'n_intervals')],
    [State('btc_update', 'figure')]
)
def updated_btc_2h(n_interval):
```

You only put one parameter in the function definition, but you're trying to pass it an `Input` and a `State`. Just update your function signature to something like:

`def updated_btc_2h(n_interval, figure_state):`

and it should resolve your error.

Comment: Thanks for the response :D It did get rid of the callback error but the chart still isn't plotting live. If I refresh the page, the last candle does change so it's not a problem with the data I'm using

Comment: There could be a problem with your `State`, because I think that should be `btc_chart` instead of `btc_update`.